# NaN loss during training of Faster R-CNN but not on SSD when using same config and data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I have successfully trained a model with Tensorflow Object Detection API on my data, using pre-trained weights from `ssd_inception_v2_coco`.

Now I am trying to train `faster_rcnn` model on the same data (the same TF Records, same label map and number of classes).

Training runs for several steps with decreasing loss and then suddenly throws an error:
`ERROR:tensorflow:Model diverged with loss = NaN.`

I have already tried:

- Decreasing learning rate (sometimes it increases the number of steps before error is thrown)
- Increasing batch size. Batch size = 24 is the largest that fits into memory.
- Checking inputs for NaNs or zero bounding boxes.
- Other `Faster R-CNN` pretrained models (`ResNet50, ResNet101, Inception V2`) from the model zoo.

Any ideas what should I check / try next?

Tensorflow version: 1.14.0

The config file (adapted from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.config)

```
# Faster R-CNN with Inception v2, configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.


model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 12
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 20
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.00002
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000002
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/data/models/faster_rcnn_inception/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the COCO dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path:  "/home/data/annotations/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/data/annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/data/annotations/val.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/data/annotations/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Comment: Please post your respective config files as an edit to your original post. I have trained using most models on the TF Object Detection API Model Zoo. Errors are usually found in the config files and every model will generally require different configurations (not just general hyperparameters). That being said, the learning rate edit is a good thought, I've had models do this prior to me reducing the learning rate by a couple decimal points.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I updated the description with the config file.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with particular images that I have in the training set as I was able to train on the subset of data. Now the questions is, how do I find the ones that cause the NaN problem ..